# BlendMode on CCSprites

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How does one set a blend mode on a CCSprite so that e.g. 2 CCSprites with the blend mode of type Multiply, will blend when they overlap in the coordindate system?

I would like to have sprites overlayed and their colors multiplied as the collide.

Is this possible in cocos2d without having to rerender the image on collision?

Comment: Blend modes change how a sprite is rendered against the background, it can not be limited to two sprites against one another unless you first render them both to a separate render texture to blend them together against a transparent background.

Comment: I accomplished this in CoreGraphics by rendering the images directly using drawInRect with a blendmode. It worked, but applying transforms on them were not smooth. Could a CCSprite not then have 3 images layered within itself, all with individual blend modes? Then I could apply CCActions to the layers themselves?